# Can I silence these two ggplot outputs?

Tags: r

I'm running a command in a function and I'd like to silence the output.

In particular, there's these two outputs that I'd like to silence

```
summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
`stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

One happens when I use group_by() %>% summarize() and the second happens when I use geom_histogram(). They're not warnings, so I don't think suppressWarnings will work.

Comment: Are you using this in markdown? You can suppress those messages by setting `warning = FALSE` and `messages = FALSE` in your chunk.

Comment: I'm using this in an R Script

Comment: The bin width one should go away if you set your own bin widths. It is notifying you of what bin width was selected automatically.

Comment: Great! Can I get rid of the other one?

Comment: Specify .groups in summarise(). E.g., `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(.groups = "keep")`

Comment: Oh the makes sense. In that case, I'll try adding ungroup() too

Comment: Will the binwidth always be 30? I'm wondering if there's logic there that I'll override

Comment: Here is the documentation. Go to geom_histogram help for more details."The default is to use the number of bins in bins, covering the range of the data. You should always override this value, exploring multiple widths to find the best to illustrate the stories in your data."

Comment: In that case, I will keep it as is and try suppress warnings()

Comment: `bins = 30` is the default. You can change `bins` or `binwidth`. Run `?stat_bin()` for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `bins` manually to override that message from being displayed regarding `geom_histogram`.

To avoid message from `summarise` use `.groups == 'keep'` as mentioned by @ LC-datascientist or use `suppressMessages`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

suppressMessages(mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, am) %>%
  summarise(mpg = sum(mpg)) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(am) + geom_histogram(bins = 10))
```